# Узнать последнее вставленное значение id в таблицу

Tags: mysql

Правильно ли  делаю

Вначале вставляю в таблицу новые данные `INSERT INTO table`

А потом чтобы получить значение id последнего вставленного значние использую

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM `table` LIMIT 0 , 1;
```

лимит тут нужен или нет и что вообще возвращает запрос без лимита?

я чтото все подзабыл, напомните кто знает

Comment: Первый совет: забывайте о mysql_* функциях, используйте PDO.
Второй: mysql_insert_id() - вернет последнюю ID-шку
Третий (по делу): LIMIT не обязателен, в результате ни в коем случае не будет больше 1 записи, но ! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id , если будет конструкция типа INSERT INTO `table` (name) VALUES ('Michael'), ('John'), ('Peter'); где id - AUTO_INCREMENT, то вам вернет ID записи с name = Michael, т.е. первой вставленой автоинкрементом ID-шки. id записей john и Peter утеряются

Answer (score 1):

Лимит не нужен, оно просто последний ид возвратит, вроде даже FROM Не надо указывать.
если в php, то там есть просто функция `mysql_insert_id()` — Get the ID generated in the last query